# Find missing dates in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have daily rainfall data from 1963, however, there a missing data points. Is there a way I can produce a list of missing dates. The date column is a POSIXct. In the form "1963-01-02" and runs to 2022-01-02 with occasional missing dates inbetween.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, create a day sequence between the start and end dates, and use `%in%` with negation (`!`) to get the dates not in the dataset column (assuming 'Date' is a column).  If it is row index, have to modify the code accordingly

```
full_dates <- seq(as.Date("1963-01-02"), as.Date("2022-01-02"), by = "1 day")
full_dates[!full_dates %in% as.Date(df1$Date)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted something a bit more robust that handles POSIXct and dates more easily, use my package timeplyr which was created for analyses involving date/datetime sequences.

```r
#remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
tseq <- time_seq("1963-01-02", "2022-01-02", by = "day")
set.seed(987654321)
dates <- sample(tseq, size = 1.5 * 10^3)
my_data <- tibble(date = dates, 
                  datetime = as_datetime(dates))

missing_dates_list <- missing_dates(my_data)
lengths(missing_dates_list)
#>     date datetime 
#>    20005    20005
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>